# WPF load texbox content at Application startup

Tags: wpf, textbox, wmi, startup

I have the following situation: A WPF app with 2 pages (using navigation). On one of the pages there is a textbox which displays some system info using WMI queries and registry data.

The problem with this approach is that that info is always refreshed when I navigate to that page, which also means that all the tasks at work behind are re-done, which makes the texbox take some time before it starts displaying the info(yeah, some WMI queries are time consuming).

Since 99 percent of that data I need doesn't need refreshing(doesn't change), how would I go about performing it only once at and then bind it to that textbox so it doesn't always refresh?

textboxt code in home.xaml.cs (the page)

```
private void TextBox1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(delegate (object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
           
        });
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(delegate (object o, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0", "ProcessorNameString", null).ToString().Replace("(R)", "").Replace("(TM)", "") + Environment.NewLine;
            TextBox1.Text += "Memory:  " + getRAMsize() + Environment.NewLine;
            TextBox1.Text += "Free Space:  " + GetTotalFreeSpace(sysdrive) + " GB" + Environment.NewLine;
            if (Is64BitSystem)
            {
                TextBox1.Text += getOS() + " 64bit" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox1.Text += getOS() + " 32bit" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            TextBox1.Text += diskname() + Environment.NewLine;
            TextBox1.Text += "MAC Address : " + System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(GetMacAddress().ToString(), ".{2}", "$&-").TrimEnd('-') + Environment.NewLine;
            TextBox1.Text += av();
        });
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

what it does vs what I want: Every time I navigate to it the textbox refreshes(textbox_loaded...of course) and it takes a second or two. I want to disable refreshing. I want it load once and keep those values until the app is opened again.

Comment: Please try to be more specific and add some of your code.

Comment: added some code.

Comment: think of it this way: My app has 2 pages . the textbox is with the info is on one of them. Everytime I navigate to it the textbox refreshes(textbox_loaded...of course) and it takes a second or two. I want to disable refreshing. I want it load once and keep those values untill the app is opened again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow...after much trial and error, I can't believe it was as easy as putting the code inside the  TextBox1_Initialized event.

```
private void TextBox1_Initialized(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(delegate (object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {

    });
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(delegate (object o, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0", "ProcessorNameString", null).ToString().Replace("(R)", "").Replace("(TM)", "") + Environment.NewLine;
        TextBox1.Text += "Memory:  " + getRAMsize() + Environment.NewLine;
        TextBox1.Text += "Free Space:  " + GetTotalFreeSpace(sysdrive) + " GB" + Environment.NewLine;
        if (Is64BitSystem)
        {
            TextBox1.Text += getOS() + " 64bit" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox1.Text += getOS() + " 32bit" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        TextBox1.Text += diskname() + Environment.NewLine;
        TextBox1.Text += "MAC Address : " + System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(GetMacAddress().ToString(), ".{2}", "$&-").TrimEnd('-') + Environment.NewLine;
        TextBox1.Text += av();
    });
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a bool flag when run the first time.

```
public void Initilize()
{
    if (!_Initilized)
    {
        _Initilized = true;

        // do initial queries here...
    }
    myusercontrol.DataContext = MyViewModel;
}
```

Comment: would this go in App.xaml.cs ? How do I bind those queries to the textbox?

Comment: I would store the datacollections in the main viewmodel, then assign the datacontext as part of the initialization. I've edited my answer.

Comment: jeez. I thought there is a easier way for a newbie like me. Have a lot of researching to do since none of those concepts are known to me. thanks anyway.